# Is it possible to boot sidekiq (redis server) when we start Rails app using 'rails server'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background-process, sidekiq

I have a Rails application running in `Ruby 2.0.0` and `Rails 3.2.16`. I'm using [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/) for setting up background jobs for a lot of automated processes like email delivery, cancellation etc.

Now, I'm starting the rails in one terminal and in next I'm starting the sidekiq.

1. Rails: `rails server -e production`
2. Sidekiq: `bundle exec sidekiq -q critical, -q high, -q default, -q low -e production`

But, I need to know whether we can start `Sidekiq` when we start rails itself not running the second command.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in to [foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) and using a Procfile.  Then you would use the command `foreman start`

Comment: If I need to start foreman then, better to stay starting with Redis server itself

Comment: No, foreman start would start up all of your processes.  Rails, redis, delayed job, anything.  Just give it a few simple definitions and you are off to the races.

Comment: Having a simple deployment script to start everything is the right way to go about this. Foreman is in fact a good way of going about this.

Comment: Is there any option inside rails itself other than this foreman gem?

Comment: @RajeshOmanakuttan : You can use Active Job if you can update your Rails version to 4.2.0 :P